# How to declare an extern array of template class objects with a forward declared template class in C++?

Tags: c++, templates, extern, forward-declaration

Consider the following existing code (which compiles and executes as expected):

```
/* File foo.h */

extern const struct Foo bar[]; /* Definition in foo.cpp */

struct Foo
{
    Foo(int i) : Foo(bar[i]) {}
    int x;
};
```

---

I now want to change `Foo` to a template class, such that:

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int i) : Foo(bar[i]) {}
    T x;
};
```

---

How do I need to declare `extern const struct Foo bar[]` now so that the code will compile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, forward declare `template <typename T> struct Foo`.
- Then, declare `bar` using the forward declared `Foo`.

---

```
template <typename T>
struct Foo;

extern const Foo<int> bar[];

template <typename T>
struct Foo
{
    Foo(int i) : Foo(bar[i]) {}
    T x;
};
```